# commands not working properly in VS Code integrated terminal (Bash)

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, angular-cli

I am using Visual Studio Code's integrated terminal, which I have changed to bash but commands like `ng` and `tsc` don't work. It doesn't recognize them.

Any guesses why that is the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you installed the angular-cli as a GLOBAL package? and also tsc and so on ...

so double check if you've done for example:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli

npm install -g tsc
```

..and so on ...

the `-g (or --globally)` param is the key .. cause it made your package 'global' on your pc

Comment: Hi Federico,

Yes, I used -g param while installing my packages but it doesn't work.

Comment: what if you try to write in the shell ng -v?

Comment: have you tried to run it as root? ..so with sudo npm install -g @angular/cli ?

Comment: Yes, that works fine on my git bash but it only bugs me inside VS terminal.

Comment: This happens if you open the angular project directly, I fixed it by opening that project with the git command `code .` it makes the commands work fine inside VS Code integrated terminal

Comment: @Zeeshanl - you seem to have a solution. But, please, can you explain better what you mean by `opening the project with the git command code` (I do not understand what you mean by that). Normally I open a VSCode project by double-clicking a VSCode-Workspace (such as `MyWorkspaceXY.code-workspace`). But if I do that, then the VSCode Terminal does not understand my Angular cmds (such as `ng g component mynewcomponent` or any other angular cmd. However, my Mac Terminal runs Angular cmds just fine. Again, what do you do in order to make Angular np cmds also work inside VSCode-Terminal ?? Thanks.

Comment: What helped me was to repeat the following cmd inside VSCode Terminal:
`npm install -g @angular/cli`

After doing so, the ng version cmd (and all the other nice angular cmds) worked well inside VSCode-Terminal.

Comment: another way is ... install BREW ..then unlink your node ..with brew unlink node .. then install nodejs .. with brew install node@10 .. then run brew link node@10 .. and finally reboot..after that try to run npm i -g @angular/cli WITHOUT sudo .. hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

Just configure you VSCode terminal to run the Node.js command prompt, usually located in:

```
c:\Program Files\nodejs\nodevars.bat
```

To run automatically, edit the config user settings like this:

```
"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": [
    "\/k C:\\\"Program Files\"\\nodejs\\nodevars.bat"
]
```